# Autoresize multiline UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, snapkit

I have tried everything to auto-resize my UILabel in Swift. I can autoresize the text when it is one line but when it is two lines it no longer works. The text in the UILabel changes often happening about every 10 seconds. The code I have tried is:

```
let direction = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 95, y: 10, width: screenWidth - 95, height:100))
direction.numberOfLines = 0
direction.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
direction.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
direction.textAlignment = .center
direction.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
direction.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
view.addSubview(direction)
direction.text = "Ffafdafafdfa fafda  dfafaf afa"

func updateDirection(update: String){
    direction.text = update
}
```

The original text "Ffafdafafdfa fafda dfafaf afa" will automatically resize but when updateDirection is called the font size with not be changed from 40. I have also tried setting the number of lines to 2 and removing the .byWordWrapping. How can I get my UILabel to resize automatically?

Comment: What is the frame of your UILabel? Should your fontSize remain static or can change to sizeToFit?

Comment: @Imad I added the frame to the code. I need to change the font size but sizeToFit just changes the size of the frame and not the font.

Comment: @Imad Its already included. Look at the above code

Comment: Remove this line: direction.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

Comment: @Imad That does not have any affect

Comment: It was working for me, if I don't have the constraints, with your code. The text came in multiple lines.

Comment: @Imad can you add an answer with your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144508/discussion-between-imad-and-smedleydslap).

Comment: let me know my answer works.

Comment: @Joe alright thank u I'll let u know when I get home

Comment: code updated...

Comment: @Joe it worked thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will keep the `frame size` and `adjust the font size` according with `direction label content`.

```
let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: UINavigationController().navigationBar.frame.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 10, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100))
let direction = UILabel()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 direction.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
 direction.numberOfLines = 0
 direction.textAlignment = .center
 direction.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
 direction.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
 direction.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
 direction.text = "This is some multiline label with a background colour" // Set or Initiate random function for your array here.

 backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
 view.addSubview(backgroundView)
 backgroundView.addSubview(direction)

 Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(random), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)  

 direction.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

 NSLayoutConstraint(item: direction,
                       attribute: .leading,
                       relatedBy: .equal,
                       toItem: backgroundView,
                       attribute: .leadingMargin,
                       multiplier: 1.0,
                       constant: 0.0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: direction,
                       attribute: .trailing,
                       relatedBy: .equal,
                       toItem: backgroundView,
                       attribute: .trailingMargin,
                       multiplier: 1.0,
                       constant: 0.0).isActive = true


NSLayoutConstraint(item: direction,
                       attribute: .top,
                       relatedBy: .equal,
                       toItem: backgroundView,
                       attribute: .topMargin,
                       multiplier: 1.0,
                       constant: 0.0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: direction,
                       attribute: .bottom,
                       relatedBy: .equal,
                       toItem: backgroundView,
                       attribute: .bottomMargin,
                       multiplier: 1.0,
                       constant: 0.0).isActive = true


}

func random(sender: Timer) {

    //Place your random func code here.     
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I need the text to fix inside a certain box though. This will resize the box to any height

Comment: Thank you for trying to help though. This has been very frustrating

Comment: @SmedleyDSlap what you mean --`This will resize the box to any height`-- you mean font size?. If you resize the box depending on direction label content size then what's the point changing font size or scale or adjust font size?

Comment: The gif linked in the answer has the box changing to different heights while the font size remains the same regardless of text length. I need the box to remain the same and the text size to change

Comment: thanks for this! especially the lines: direction.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
 direction.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

Answer (score 0):

Try this without Constraints:

```
    let direction = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 95, y: 10, width: 375 - 95, height:100))
    direction.numberOfLines = 0
    direction.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    direction.textAlignment = .center
    direction.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
    direction.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
    view.addSubview(direction)

    direction.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard"
```

Comment: The first time I set the text value it resizes but the second time it does not resize

Answer (score 0):

I will try this code
It is use full

first create one function

```
func calchight(strin:String) -> CGFloat
   {
       let label =  UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
       label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = strin
       label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height + 2
   }
```

---

then call this function in your right place, when you want to resize label

/--------------

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    { 
        let heit = self.calchight(strin: StringObject)

        return (heit)
    }
```

/--------------------------

this code is useful and not require Auto layout containers

Answer (score 0):

`UILabel` will consider its content size to be one line of text, even when `numberOfLines` is set to a non-zero value, unless `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is also set.

In other words, it can't predict how to wrap the text without `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, so it doesn't plan to. It seems like during the autolayout process, a `UILabel` doesn't know how to balance the priority between its width set by layout constraints outside of it and the wrapping of text.

So it doesn't exert any additional pressure (more than the height of one line) on the vertical dimension even when its Content Compression Resistance is higher than other views', because it will assume that by exerting pressure in the horizontal axis, its content will be displayed.

So the solution is to set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, so that it is able to determine the height of the content *after wrapping the text* and then it uses that content size to negotiate layout with other views.

You probably want to avoid hard-coding the width of your `UILabel`. Assuming that its container's width is not going to change based on autolayout, it should be safe to use that. In this case I'm in a `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionViewCell` and the "title label" spans the full width of the cell.

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() {
    // Tell the label it should wrap text at the same width as this cell's contentView.
    titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = contentView.frame.width

    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using function sizetofit() after assigning text to your label. 
like:

```
direction.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: This changes the frame of the UILabel and does not change the font size

Comment: try removing line  direction.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

Comment: I tried but it not work I updated the question with more details

Comment: try below code:    let direction = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 95, y: 10, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, height:100));    direction.numberOfLines = 0
        direction.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        direction.textAlignment = .center
        direction.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
        self.view.addSubview(direction)
        direction.text = "abc "
        direction.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray